# Running MATLAB from Mac OSX terminal

Tags: macos, matlab, terminal

I'd love to run matlab from the terminal on my Macbook (running Lion), forgoing the standalone matlab interface. All the information I've found online suggests that the command is simply something along the lines of

```
$ matlab
```

followed by various tags (-nojvm, -nodesktop, -nosplash, etc.). When I run this from the terminal, I get

```
Js-MacBook-Pro:~ joehuchette$ matlab -nodesktop
-bash: matlab: command not found
```

I'm pretty inexperienced with this sort of thing, so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, put a symbolic link to the Matlab binary in your path:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/MATLAB_RXXXx.app/bin/matlab /usr/local/bin
```

where XXXXx is the Matlab version.

Answer (score 0):

Where is matlab located on your machine? The error you're getting indicates that it's not in the normal search path, so you'll need to either add the path:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/matlab
```

or use a full path to invoke matlab:

```
$ /path/to/matlab
```